# Transaction not updating data in smart contract web3.py

Tags: web3.py, infura, smart-contract-wallets

I have a smart contract written in Solidity that stores a blacklist of strings. I have written methods to add strings to the blacklist as well as check if a particular string is present in the blacklist. These methods are called `addBlacklist()` and `retrieveBlacklist()` respectively. I've deployed the smart contract on a Web3 API project on Infura and passed its URL, my metamask wallet account number, and the account's private key to my Web3 code in Python.

The current problem that I'm facing is that transactions to the smart contract are not making any changes to the contract and not updating the blacklist. This is evident from the below code where, after retrieval of the string '127.0.0.212' after adding it to the blacklist yields `false`.

```
ipblacklist_sol = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, address="0xB0CA9272BF4a2C68ec3702d14C1bdC5A4Ee6E9af")
add_blacklist = ipblacklist_sol.functions.addBlacklist('127.0.0.212').buildTransaction(
    {"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, "chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce + 3}
)
sign_add_blacklist = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(add_blacklist, private_key=private_key)
tx_add_blacklist_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_add_blacklist.rawTransaction)
# tx_add_blacklist_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_add_blacklist_hash)

print(ipblacklist_sol.functions.retrieveBlacklist('127.0.0.212').call())
```

I commented out the receipt line because that seemed to time out the operation after 120 seconds. The image given below is the result I get. It says that the IP is not added to the blacklist.

[image]

But if I create a new contract each time right above this piece of code, and immediately pass the new contract's address to the above code, then the IP address is added to the blacklist.

```
IPBlacklist = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
# set up transaction from constructor which executes when firstly
transaction = IPBlacklist.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, "chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce}
)
signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)


ipblacklist_sol = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, address=tx_receipt.contractAddress)
add_blacklist = ipblacklist_sol.functions.addBlacklist('127.0.0.212').buildTransaction(
    {"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, "chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce + 3}
)
sign_add_blacklist = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(add_blacklist, private_key=private_key)
tx_add_blacklist_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_add_blacklist.rawTransaction)
tx_add_blacklist_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_add_blacklist_hash)

print(ipblacklist_sol.functions.retrieveBlacklist('127.0.0.212').call())
```

This seems to work, but it creates a new contract each time, which is obviously not what I want. In the first piece of code that I've given here, I passed an existing contract's address in place of the `tx_recipt.contractAddress` to try and update data on the existing contract. I need help calling transactions to an existing contract.

Comment: From my experience the best way to know what’s the problem is to look in your local blockchain logs - ganache for example will print logs for each transaction. See if you see errors like “Out of gas”. From your code I see you don’t pass gas to the call but it will be more helpful if you provide the logs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139809/discussion-on-answer-by-matank001-transaction-not-updating-data-in-smart-contrac).